# How to add LatLng from leaflet to WordPress custom fields?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, leaflet

I use leaflet. I have a form for adding posts from front-end. I must get current `latlng` coordinates and add them to WordPress custom fields. I think I can use input like this

```
document.write('<input type=\'text\' name=\'position\' value = \'' + latlng + '\'');
```

How to get `latlng` in variable?

Comment: I improved the formatting for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
var positions = document.getElementsByName('position'); //the list of position
var position = positions[i] // the index of position in the document
```